# how to get default store view label on magento

Tags: magento

I have this code:

```
$options = ($_Item->getProductOptions());
```

How I can have the default view label name of the option and not of the translated store view one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this particular code depends on the class of the `$item` object.
Theoretically, you would get the default view label by loading the product in admin store:

`Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(0)->load(PRODUCT_ID);`

In your case, it might be something close to:

`$productId = $item->getProductId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(0)->load($productId);
$label = $product->getName();`

`setStoreId(0)` before loading the object is the key component.